# JavaScript code unexpected results after incrementing numbers

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve this out:

```
x = 10; y = 0; z = 5;

y = z * x++

y = z * ++x
```

The instruction maunal (500 pages long) that I am reading all it tells me is that the answer to the x++ problem is:

```
y = 50 and x = 11.
```

I know how to get the x++ all you have to do is add an increment of 1.

```
x = x + 1.
```

Can someone please help me, because I cant figure out what I am doing wrong! I am not understanding where the book got 50 from!

Comment: This has got to be a dup of lots of questions...

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are having here deal with post-incrementation and pre-incrementation.

When doing `x++`, you are post-incrementing... This means that the incrementation will only occur after the statement has been evaluated.

So, given the following code:

```
x = 10; y = 0; z = 5;

y = z * x++;
```

JavaScript does this:

```
x = 10; y = 0; z = 5;

y = z * x++;

// Ignore Post-Increment, Evalutate
y = z * x;
y = 5 * 10;
y = 50;

// Now Increment x - POST-INCREMENT
x = x + 1;
x = 10 + 1;
x = 11;
```

When doing `++x`, you are pre-incrementing... This means that the incrementation will occur before the statement is evaluated:

```
x = 10; y = 0; z = 5;

y = z * ++x;

// Do Pre-Increment
x = x + 1;
x = 10 + 1;
x = 11;

// Evaluate
y = z * x;
y = 5 * 11;
y = 55;
```

Answer (score 2):

The result of a post-increment expression is the value before the variable has been incremented.

So this:

```
y = z * x++;
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
y = z * x;     // y = 50
x = x + 1;     // x = 11 (the increment is done afterwards)
```

On the other hand, a pre-increment operation evaluates to the value after the increment. So this:

```
y = z * ++x;
```

is roughly equivalent to this:

```
x = x + 1;     // x = 11  (the increment is done first)
y = z * x;     // y = 55
```

Answer (score 1):

x++ increase x by after value is delivered:

```
 y = z * x++   // 5 * 10  // and 10 become 11 after operation
```

++x increase x by before value is delivered:

```
 y = z * ++x   // 5 * 11
```

fancy names post and pre incrementations

Answer (score 1):

You should understand the difference between post-increment and pre-increment operators here.

In the `y = z * x++` case, x if first used in the expression and later incremented. Thus the value of the expression becomes `y = 5 * 10` after which the value of x is incremented to 11.

In the other case, the pre-increment operator is used. So it's first incremented and used later. Thus the value becomes 55 in that case.

Answer (score 1):

It is post incrememt operator.
x++  use value of x, then increment it
++x  ( pre increment) increment x, then use it

Answer (score 0):

`++` after the variable is a post-increment operation, that is, `x` is incremented after the assignment is made.

In other words, y is calculated to be 50 *and then* x is incremented.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
a * (b++)
```

It's the same as:

```
a * b;
b = b + 1; //POST increment
```

---

but

```
a * (++b);
```

is the same like this:

```
b = b + 1; //PRE increment
a * b;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have

```
x = 10;
y = 0;
z = 5;
```

then you do:

```
y = z * x++  = 5 * 10 = 50
```

after that you get:

```
y = 50;
x = 11; (because x = x+1)
```

then:

```
y = z * ++x  = 5  * 11 = 55
```

Comment: say that it was ++x, what would my answer be then?

Comment: ok that makes sense. I see what I have to do for that. I have to do the 10 + 1 = 11 then times it by 5. y = 55 and x = 11 still or do they each need to have their own variables?

Comment: You can do several assigments in one line as suggested by all here, as ` z * x++ ` (one line) is the same as two lines of code:
`z * x;`
`x = x + 1;`, so you only have to write the style that better suits you.